# Getting trouble in page redirection

Tags: php, yii, http-redirect

I have the following screen in  my project.Everthing is working fine other than the redirection link of View.As you can see it is poping up the validation error.I have no idea why its comming.Even,I am redirecting to diffrent model.[image]

I want to go the diffrent page when clicking View.

I have the following code in my view.

```
//codes//
<div class="view" id="id">
    <?php 

                echo "<h4>Name : " .       $value['name']. "</h4>";
                echo "<h4>Skills : " .     $value['key_skills'] . "</h4>";
                echo "<h4>Category : " .   $value['title']. "</h4>";
                echo "<h4>Experience : " . $value['experience'] . " Years.</h4>";
               // echo CHtml::submitButton('View Details', array('name' => 'viewemployeedetails')); 
                echo CHtml::button('View',array(
                     'submit'=>array('SiteContoller/actionViewEmployeeDetails',array('id'=>$value['id'])),
));
     ?>
</div>
```

I have tried few things...but its not working.

Comment: If the button is still in the form tag you might be submitting the form to its `action`. Have you tried a link instead of a button?

Comment: like this <?php echo CHtml::link('Link Text',array('controller/action')); ?> have  not tried yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the 'Controller' text part and 'action' text part from:

```
'SiteContoller/actionViewEmployeeDetails'
```

and use

```
'site/viewEmployeeDetails'
```

if you want it to go to `SiteController`'s `actionViewEmployeeDetails` action

Answer (score 1):

You should use `CHtml::link` not `CHtml::button` unless you are posting data to the address. You can use css to style your link to look and visually behave like a button. In addition there is no `submit` attribute for `button` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button